# Prettifying or Coloring the html on web-page for better readibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, syntax-highlighting

I am writing a code on my website to explain certain html code like this:

[image: Sample Text code]

I can see the very same thing on w3schools, but it is better colored and more helpful to understand.
[image: Colored Text code]
I cannot make out which library they used for this? Is there any .js plugin or library to help 'colorify' the plain html code for better readibilty? Kindly help.

Any js-fiddle or plunker would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [prism](http://prismjs.com/) or [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/)?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [prism](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) and [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/), already mentioned by [sandeep s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341885/sandeep-s) in the comment, you might want to give [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) a look.

The one used by W3C seems coded specifically for them. Here's the relevant part of their [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/stdtheme.css):

```css
.w3-code {
  font-family: Consolas, "courier new";
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-left: 4px solid #009688;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.w3-code {
  border-left: 4px solid #73AD21 !important;
}
.w3-example,
.w3-code,
.w3-reference {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
/*STYLES HENTET FRA STDTHEME, FOR Å FÅ EXEMPLER, TABELLER OG TRYITKNAPPER TIL Å SE UT SOM DE GJØR PÅ W3SCHOOLS:*/
.highCOM {color:green;}
.highELE {color:brown;}
.highATT {color:crimson;}
.highATT {color:red;}
.highVAL {color:mediumblue;}
.highGLB {color:#CC9900;}
.highLT, .highGT {color:blue;}
span.marked {
  color:#e80000;
  background-color:transparent;
}
span.deprecated {
  color:#e80000;
  background-color:transparent;
}
p.intro {
  font-size:16px;
}
div.tutintro {
  width:auto;
  min-height:132px;
}
div.tutintro img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
div.tutintro p {
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size:16px;
}
code {
  font-size:105%;
  color:crimson;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  padding:1px 4px;
}
.html5badge {
  /*position:relative;*/
  background-image:url('/images/html5_badge20.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:right;
}
.notsupported,.notsupported:hover,.notsupported:active,.notsupported:visited,.notsupported:link {
  color:rgb(197,128,128)
}
/*.html5badge:after {
  content:"\f13b";
  font-family:FontAwesome;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#e34f26;
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  right:0px;
  top:0;
}*/
div.chapter, div.nav {
  font-size:20px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
a.chapter:link    {color:#73AD21;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;}
a.chapter:visited {color:#73AD21;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;}
a.chapter:hover   {color:#73AD21;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:underline;}
a.chapter:active  {color:#73AD21;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:underline;}
div.chapter div.prev {
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.chapter div.next {
  width:48%;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div.nav div.prev {
  width:22%;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.nav div.home, div.nav div.video {
  margin-left:3%;
  width:46%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.nav div.next {
  width:28%;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
a.w3-btn, a.w3-btn:link, a.w3-btn:visited {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#73AD21;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
a.w3-btn:hover,a.w3-btn:active {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  color:#73AD21;
  box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
a.w3-btn[href*="exercise.asp"] {
  margin:10px 5px 0 0;
}
a.btnplayit,a.btnplayit:link,a.btnplayit:visited {
  background-color:#FFAD33;
  padding:1px 10px 2px 10px;
}
a.btnplayit:hover,a.btnplayit:active {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  color:#FFAD33;
}
a.btnsmall:link,a.btnsmall:visited,a.btnsmall:active,a.btnsmall:hover {
  float:right;
  padding:1px 10px 2px 10px;
  font:15px Verdana, sans-serif;
}
a.btnsmall:active,a.btnsmall:hover {
  color:#73AD21;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
div.tryit_ex {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  overflow:auto;
}
div.tryit_ex img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px
}
div.tryit_ex h2 {
  margin-top:5px;
}
table.tecspec {
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
}
table.tecspec>thead>tr>th, table.tecspec>tbody>tr>th, table.tecspec>tfoot>tr>th, table.tecspec>thead>tr>td, table.tecspec>tbody>tr>td, table.tecspec>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table.tecspec th {
    text-align:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #mainLeaderboard {
    height:60px;
  }
  #div-gpt-ad-1422003450156-0 {
    float:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
  }
  #div-gpt-ad-1422003450156-3 {
    float:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
  }
  .prev .chapter, .next .chapter, .home .chapter, .video .chapter {
    color:transparent !important;
  }
  .prev .chapter::after, .next .chapter::after, .home .chapter::after, .video .chapter::after {
    position:absolute !important;
    color:#73AD21 !important;
  }
  .prev .chapter::after {
    content: "\ab" !important;
    left:15px !important;
    font-size:30px !important;
  }
  .next .chapter::after {
    content: "\bb" !important;
    right:15px !important;
    font-size:30px !important;
  }
  .home .chapter::after {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    font-size:30px;
    content: "\e800";
    left:47%; 
  }
  .video .chapter::after {
    content: "\f008";
    left:49%;
    font-size:24px;
  }
  .homeOperaMini .chapter::after {
    content: "Home";
    left:47%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-code notranslate htmlHigh">
  <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">!DOCTYPE</span>  <span class="highATT">html</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">html</span>  <span class="highATT">lang=</span><span class="highVAL">"en-US"</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
  <br><span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">script</span>  <span class="highATT">src=</span><span class="highVAL">"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span><span class="highLT">&lt;</span>
  <span
  class="highELE">/script</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
    <br>
    <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">body</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">div</span>  <span class="highATT">ng-app=</span><span class="highVAL">""</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
    <br>&nbsp; <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">p</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>Name : <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">input</span>  <span class="highATT">type=</span><span class="highVAL">"text"</span> 
    <span
    class="highATT">ng-model=</span><span class="highVAL">"name"</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span><span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">/p</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
      <br>&nbsp; <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">h1</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>Hello <span class="highATT">{{name}}</span><span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">/h1</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
      <br>
      <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">/div</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">/body</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
      <br>
      <span class="highLT">&lt;</span><span class="highELE">/html</span><span class="highGT">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I too found that, but I dont want the whole code to be laboriously written with classes. I wanted something that can do this automatically ... ;(